# How can I replace/update a database without relying in a cloud service?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a database program which has admin forms and user forms. The first one can add new data to the database, the second can't. I was thinking in a form of update the database the non-admins use but without requesting a cloud service.
Can anyone suggest me a way to update the database for the normal users without relying on GCS? I was thinking in just add a navigator in the program, and tell them to download the database, and adding a file replacement. Is it too risky/dirty?

Comment: Is this a windows app or a web app? How will you know who is who? You will need some sort of login.

Comment: I have no need to know who is using the program, which btw is a Windows app. There will be a max of 3 people working on it, and not simultanously. In fact, it's so simple that the users are not included in the database. BUT, I need that connectivity, or at least a simple way to modify the database as an admin user, and retrieve that updated database with a normal user.

Comment: This is what database migrations are for